# will 'printf' always do its job?

Tags: c, printf

```
printf("/*something else*/"); /*note that:without using \n in printf*/
```

I know printf() uses a buffer which prints whatever it contains when, in the line buffer, "\n" is seen by the buffer function.  So when we forget to use "\n" in printf(), rarely, line buffer will not be emptied. Therefore, printf() wont do its job.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Could you explain your question better? What do you mean by *safe* and *always work*?

Comment: Ok, from your question updates, it sounds like you want to read about line buffering...

Comment: Yes, `printf` will always do it's job.  But part of it's job is to buffer data and `stdout` is normally line buffered.  So without a `\n` the data may not be flushed but it is safe in a buffer.  If you need to flush the buffer before a newline you can just call `fflush(stdout)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you gave above is safe as there are no variable arguments to `printf`. However it is possible to specify a format string and supply variables that do not match up with the format, which can deliver unexpected (and unsafe) results. Some compilers are taking a more proactive approach with `printf` use case analysis, but even then one should be very, very careful when `printf` is used.

Answer (score 2):

From my man page:

> These functions return the number of characters printed (not including
>   the trailing `\0` used to end output to strings) or a negative value
>   if an output error occurs, except for `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()`, which
>   return the number of characters that would have been printed if the n
>   were unlimited (again, not including the final `\0`).

So, it sounds like the can fail with a negative error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, output to `stdout` in C (using `printf`) is normally line buffered. This means that `printf()` will collect output until either:

- the buffer is full, or
- the output contains a `\n` newline

If you want to force the output of the buffer, call `fflush(stdout)`. This will work even if you have printed something without a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Also printf and friends can fail.

Common implementations of C call malloc() in the printf family of the stdC library.
malloc can fail, so then will printf.  In UNIX the write() call can be interrupted by EINTR, so context switching in UNIX will trigger faults (EINTR).  Windows can and will do similar things.

And... Although you do not see it posted here often you should always check the return code from any system or library function that returns a value.

Comment: `fprintf`, `fwrite` etc, don't have issues with signals, AFAIK

Comment: In UNIX the underlying system call for all of the printf functions
that do temrinal, socket, file etc., I/O is write().  Write will fail due to a signal - EINTR, for example.  write is not atomic.
For example see: 
http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/2/write/

Comment: 'nother point - this is glibc base module code (vfprintf) - cse in point malloc:
workstart = (CHAR_T *) malloc ((width + 32) * sizeof (CHAR_T));
if (workstart == NULL)
  {
    done = -1;
    goto all_done;
  }

meaning: [whichever]printf() will fail if malloc fails.

Answer (score 0):

Like that, no.  It won't always work as you expect, especially if you're using user input as the format string.  If the first argument has %s or %d or other format specifiers in it, they will be parsed and replaced with values from the stack, which can easily break if it's expecting a pointer and gets an int instead.

This way tends to be a lot safer:

```
printf("%s", "....");
```

The output buffer will be flushed before exit, or before you get input, so the data will make it regardless of whether you send a \n.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` could fail for any number of reasons. If you're deep in recursion, calling `printf` may blow your stack. The C and C++ standards have little to say on threading issues and calling `printf` while `printf` is executing in another thread may fail. It could fail because `stdout` is attached to a file and you just filled your filesystem, in which case the return value tells you there was a problem. If you call `printf` with a string that isn't zero terminated then bad things could happen. And `printf` can *apparently* fail if you're using buffered I/O and your buffer hasn't been flushed yet.